# Springfox Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springfox

I'm trying to use SpringFox.

Spring Boot version: 'org.springframework.boot:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

*build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
...
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-petstore:2.10.5'
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-oas:3.0.0"
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
...
}
```

*Spring Boot Class*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableOpenApi
public class ServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*SwaggerUiWebMvcConfigurer*

```
@Component
public class SwaggerUiWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final String baseUrl;

    public SwaggerUiWebMvcConfigurer(
        @Value("${springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url:}") String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String baseUrl = StringUtils.trimTrailingCharacter(this.baseUrl, '/');
        registry.
            addResourceHandler(baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/")
            .resourceChain(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController(baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/")
            .setViewName("forward:" + baseUrl + "/swagger-ui/index.html");
    }
}
```

*SwaggerConfig*

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket petApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("full-petstore-api")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .paths(any())
            .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("API")
            .description("Service API")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("http://springfox.io")
            .contact(new Contact("springfox", "", ""))
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/LICENSE")
            .version("2.0")
            .build();
    }
}
```

*SecurityConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

When I start task 'bootRun', I get an error:

```
[  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

I tried to use SpringFox demo projects examples and SpringFox-Boot, but I get this error every time.

Comment: Spring BOot 3 is for JakartaEE **not** JavaEE. Use 2.6 not 3.0, afaik there is no SpringFox version available for Spring Boot 3 (mainly due to that still being developed and not becoming final for about 6 to 7 months).

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks a lot. While I looking for a solution, I found the indicated problem on GitHub: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3983

I couldn't find an indication of Spring version support, until you answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Spring Boot 3.0 is built for Java17 and JakartaEE, **not** JavaEE. Spring Boot 3 is still under development and hasn't seen a final release yet. There has been no official release date yet, but expect nothing sooner than Q4 of 2022. Until then I wouldn't consider Spring Boot 3 for production (or maybe when they start releasing Release Candidates).

That being said, there is currently no SpringFox release that supports JakartaEE and therefore isn't usable with Spring Boot 3 (see [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3983)). So until that has been resolved the combination of SpringFox and Spring Boot 3 won't work.

Use 2.6.x (which at this moment is the latest release version of Spring Boot).

Comment: Migrating to springdoc-openapi ist the way to go instead of downgrading spring boot (which is not always an option). Springfox is essentially abandoned, because the last update in the GitHub repository has been in 2020.

Answer (score 35):

### SHORT AND PRACTICAL SOLUTION:

For the integration between **spring-boot** and **swagger-ui**, delete all **Springfox** related dependencies and just add the following library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional configuration is needed):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The **Swagger UI** page will then be available at

> *http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html*

---

### MORE DETAILS:

The **Swagger** (currently known as **OpenAPI**) is a specification for visualizing web services. **Springfox** is an implemetation of the specification which is no longer maintained by the owners and last commit of the project is in *October 2020*. At the time, `javax` namespace was used by Spring framework, but in newer versions of Spring the namespace has been changed to `jakarta`.

**Springfox** still uses old version namespace (`javax`), and of course it does not match with newer versions of Spring framework, so you have to:

- Downgrade your *Spring-Boot* version to older one (2.7) or
- Use another *OpenAPI* implementation.

I suggest you to use **springdoc-openapi** library instead. *[Base on the official documentation](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started)*:

> springdoc-openapi java library helps to automate the generation of API
> documentation using spring boot projects. springdoc-openapi works by
> examining an application at runtime to infer API semantics based on
> spring configurations, class structure and various annotations.

***Notice:***

- If you have context-path then *http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html*.
- For spring-boot v3.x support, make sure you use springdoc-openapi **latest version**.

Comment: You are just awesome !

Comment: Why is spring-boot-starter-validation included?

Comment: @aherocalledFrog Good point, I'd written the answer based on version 2.0.2 of the library and it needed validation dependency, in the latest version of the library it doesn't need more configuration. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` works perfectly without much configuration. Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm surprised to see ads in the official documentation link. Wondering if it's actually the official docs.

Answer (score 9):

Just add this dependency into the pom.xml

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

if necessary, also add this property into your application.properties

`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER`

source: [Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' in spring data rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241843/failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsbootstrapper-in-spring-data-rest)

Comment: Very good answer. Work like clockwork

Comment: This could make it work, but it is not the right solution, see others responses.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger does not support Spring Boot 3.0 version. Instead use OpenAPI which is the updated Swagger.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

i used this one it's works without any configuration .thanks

Answer (score 0):

For SpringBoot version 3 and above just add this dependency in pom.xml to run swagger

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But if you want to use SpringFox dependencies first you need to downgrade SpringBoot to below version 3

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Then add SpringFox dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Make SwaggerConfig class

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.controller")) // Specify the package containing your controllers
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("API Documentation")
            .description("Documentation for your API")
            .version("1.0")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Lastly add ANT_PATH_MATCHER in application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Swagger-ui will run in http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html